# How to find database records that do not have associations?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Say I have this simplified model setup

User:

```
has_many :logs
```

Log:

```
attr_accessible :key, :value
belongs_to :user
```

When a user is contacted, the app creates a log for this event with

```
Log.create(user: user, key: "contacted", value: "by admin")
```

There are many other types of logs, differentiated by their `key` attribute value.

I am trying to write a scope that will return all users that have never been contacted.
So far I have

```
scope :never_contacted, -> { joins(:logs).where.not("logs.key = ?", "contacted").uniq }
```

Unfortunately this seems to only return users that have logs other than "contacted" and leaves out users that have no logs at all.

I am thinking it may be possible to "inverse" a positive query, for example

```
scope :contacted, -> { joins(:logs).where("logs.key = ?", "contacted").uniq }
scope :never_contacted, -> { (all - contacted) }
```

but I also suspect such an approach would be very inefficient.

Is it possible to query for users that do not have an associated log with "contacted" as key attribute?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to achieve the corrects result with a single SQL query, but you need a little bit good old SQL.

```
User.joins("LEFT JOIN logs ON logs.user_id = users.id").where("logs.id IS NULL")
```

The code above forces a [LEFT JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) (as by default AR creates an INNER JOIN) and fetches all the users where there is no corresponding log in the `logs` table.

You can package it as a scope

```
scope :never_contacted, -> { joins("LEFT JOIN logs ON logs.user_id = users.id").where("logs.id IS NULL") }
```

Comment: Won't this query return only users that have no logs? What about those users who have some other logs besides "contacted"?

Comment: Just add an extra OR condition in the WHERE.

Answer (score 0):

I'd query SQL directly with `OR` condition if it's about efficiency.

```
scope :never_contacted, -> { joins(:logs).where("logs.key IS NULL OR logs.key <> ?", "contacted").uniq }
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks perfect. I still find it odd though that the cases of "no logs" and "only other logs" have to be handled seperatly. Guess SQL was not designed for negative lookup.

Comment: This does not cut it either. "logs.key IS NULL" only returns users with logs that have no key, not users without logs. If only there was a way to combine this answer with that by Simone Carletti.